# Can't able to create table using ORE.create

Tags: r, oracle

I had executed the R program and when I try to push the result to a table using

```
ore.create(score, table="xyz")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  :
  ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P007, instance XY.ab.dc.cd:abc (2)
ORA-06520: PL/SQL: Error loading external library
ORA-06522: /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/librqe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ORA-06512: at "RQSYS.RQROWEVALIMPL", line 20
ORA-06512: at "RQSYS.RQROWEVALIMPL", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Please help to solve this issue since I tried to solve this for the past 1 week and I cant able to as I am new to this.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with your installation of Oracle R package.

The message indicates your are running on 11gR2.  ORE requires 11.2.0.3 or higher, or 11.2.0.1 with a specific patch applied.  Check this [OTN Forum thread for details](https://community.oracle.com/message/10952904).

You need an Oracle Support contract to get hold of these patches.  If you don't have a contract you will need to migrate to database 12c in order to use R.